# How can I render the text under the player?

Tags: python, pygame

Hey basically first time working with text in pygame, was just wondering how to render the text under the player / enemy.

[image]

Here's the game loop:

```
#text test
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30)) #bakgrundsfärg på spelet


    if game_over == False:

        #timer
        timer = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

        #update
        player_group.update()
        enemy_group.update()

        #draw
        player_group.draw(screen)
        enemy_group.draw(screen)
        

    #gui
    life_gui = font.render("Life : " + str(p_hp), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(life_gui, (10, 10))

    time_gui = font.render("Time : " + str(int(timer/1000)), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(time_gui, (10, 720))

    kills_gui = font.render("Kills : " + str(kill_counter), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(kills_gui, (10, 760))


    #game over screen
    if game_over == True:
        game_over_screen = font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(game_over_screen, (300, 350))
    

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Accidentaly forgot to include the game loop before but have added it now.
If anyone knows that would be a great help! (:

Comment: Could you post the code containing the text? It would be easier to answer if people could  see what you have already done / tried.

Comment: Food for thought: How and when do you decide where to render the player? How and when do you tell pygame where to render the text? Could you combine both?

Comment: Yeah sorry for forgetting it but i've added the game loop now where I render the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, just needed to render the text before the player... haha

```
#text test
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30)) #bakgrundsfärg på spelet


    #gui
    life_gui = font.render("Life : " + str(p_hp), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(life_gui, (10, 10))

    time_gui = font.render("Time : " + str(int(timer/1000)), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(time_gui, (10, 720))

    kills_gui = font.render("Kills : " + str(kill_counter), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(kills_gui, (10, 760))

    if game_over == False:

        #timer
        timer = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

        #update
        player_group.update()
        enemy_group.update()

        #draw
        player_group.draw(screen)
        enemy_group.draw(screen)


    #game over screen
    if game_over == True:
        game_over_screen = font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(game_over_screen, (300, 350))
    

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```